# Is there a delay in calling home screen intent?

Tags: android

I'm implementing an application locker for android.
I have the following code in my onPause() of authentication activity where user has to enter his password.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        blnSwitchingActivity = true;
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
}
```

The following scenario creates a problem.

1. The user first clicks on any app.
2. The authentication activity is opened. The user can either enter his password or go back.
3. If he goes back, in onPause i'm calling home screen intent.
4. The problem is when the user clicks on home screen, he has to wait for a few seconds to open any other app.

**My question**: Why there is a delay in calling the home screen intent?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure of what your question is, but it sounds like some combination of `android:noHistory=true` and `android:excludeFromRecents=true` for the `Activity` in your manifest would do the trick for you.

Comment: Oh sorry, I've rephrased my question.

Comment: Are you sure `onPause()` is the best place to be killing your `Activity` and going back to the home screen? This means that any time your `Activity` is out of view (phone screen turned off, for instance), the user will be sent back to the home screen.

Comment: Yes. basically I don't want the user to kill this activity in any case. If its been killed the user should go to the home screen. Remember this is app locker - If he kills the activity then he will gain access to any other app.

Comment: Turning the screen on and off is not an attempt to kill your `Activity` though. How are you intercepting the launch of the "locked" `Activity` anyway?